# Is it possible to declare variables in a YAML file and to recover those variables in the .gitlab-ci.yml and use them in a matrix job?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I am configuring a Gitlab C/I that will trigger several child pipelines in another project.

Each one of the child projects and pipelines needs two variables (foo and bar) and I want to trigger them in parallel, with a matrix job.

The number of child projects and pipelines will change, and I want to keep the configuration simple. If a new project needs to be added, I only want to add the two needed variables in a file and nothing else.

So, I imagined this configuration:

First the file where the variables will be stored:

```yaml
# variables.yml
matrix_variables:
  - foo: "single value for foo"
    bar: "single value for bar"
  - foo: "another single value for foo"
    bar: "antoher single value for bar"
```

Then, the .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml
    include:
      - local: variables.yml
    stages:
      - example
        example_job:
     stage: example
     script:
      - echo "foo is $foo"
      - echo "bar is $bar"
    parallel:
     matrix:
      - extends: matrix_variables
```

But when pushing and run on my gitlab project, I get the following error labelled with "YAML invalid" and "error":

```
jobs matrix variables config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword
```

I then tried to add a dummy script to my `variables.yml` and even inside the matrix job in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`, but still the same error.

My question is: **Is what I am trying to achieve even possible, if yes, how ?**

My gitlab instance is running with the Community Edition 15.91.

Comment: The problem there is that you are using the `extends` key under `matrix`, which does not accept any keyword but variables instead. See [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallelmatrix)

Comment: @bhito If I understand this correctly, that means I cannot execute a matrix job while using variables from another yaml in anyways possible ?

Comment: That's correct, it expect the variables to exist there beforehand, it won't compute any values. From what I see, you have two options: 1 - Use YAML anchors and define the variables that way so you can refer to them later on. 2 - Use dynamic child pipelines with JSONnet which will create dynamic jobs based on your configuration, [here's an example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/project-templates/jsonnet/?_gl=1%2a19vz9g1%2a_ga%2aNzQ5Mjk1Mjg1LjE2MzU4MzkxODM.%2a_ga_ENFH3X7M5Y%2aMTY4MzI4MTI1NS4yMDMuMS4xNjgzMjgxMjY4LjAuMC4w)

Comment: Ok, that is really helpful, I will take a look to your link, thank you @bhito

Answer (score 0):

Rename `matrix_variables` to `.matrix_variables`. See the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/#hide-jobs):
"You can use hidden jobs that start with . as templates for reusable configuration with:
The extends keyword."